# Selection Row in EXTJS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller

I am using a extjs grid and trying to get the selected row in a popup from the grid.
Usecase:
1) Have a grid with modify button on top
2) Select a row and click the button to open popup
3) Trying to show data in the popup
the getSelectionModel() is returnign empty.
The popup is in controller.

Following is the code

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MakerController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

models : [],

stores : ['AllowedAccessStore'],

views : [ 'makertabpanel','userinfogrid' ],

init : function() {
    this.control({
        'makertabpanel button[name= addNewUser]' : {
            click : this.openDialog
        },

        'makertabpanel button[name= modifyUser]' : {
            click : this.openmodifyDialog
        }
    });
},
,
openmodifyDialog : function() {
    console.log("userinfoGrid 1:"+this.getUserinfoGrid());
    var userinfoGrid = Ext.getCmp('userinfogridID');
    console.log("userinfoGrid:"+userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().getCount()); // Returns 0
    console.log("hasSelection:"+ userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection());

    if (userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
       var row = userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
       console.log(row.get('id'));

       this.userId = Ext.getCmp('usernameID').setValue(row.get('id'));
       this.userFName = Ext.getCmp('userFirstName').setValue(row.get('fname'));
       this.userLName = Ext.getCmp('userLastName').setValue(row.get('lname'));
    }

    //this.openDialog();
},
.
.
.
```

Comment: what is returning in `userinfogrid`? `getSelectionModel().getSelection()` is the right set of methods to get selected item(s).  As a side-note if you use a form within your popup window you can use loadRecord to load all fields at once. `myForm.getForm().loadRecord(selectedRecord);` There is an example of that [here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/extjs4-mvc-grid-binded-form/viewer.html)

Comment: userinfogrid shows [object object] in the firebug. I checked the ID it is returning the grid id.

Comment: This approach did not work so I changed my design to encorporate the suggestion by @weeksdev. Not sure if the issue is with my design which is nested.